Python using local variables in a module def
Can I access a local variable in a module?
For example my main.py script has the variable a and I want my module function to print a
# main.py
import sys
import os
sys.path.insert(0, os.path.abspath(r'C:\MyModules'))
import mymodule

a = 'It worked'
mymodule.test()

The below file is saved in the MyModules folder.
# mymodule.py
def test():
    print(a)

If I add a = 'It worked' into mymodule.py it gets printed when I run main.py.
clearly the above is only an example to demonstrate functionalliy.

In this example, a is a global variable in main.py and a free variable in test(), so what do you mean by "local variable"?

This might be of interest: What does if name == "main": do?

'a' apears to only be able to be used in main.py meaning it's local to that code. If it was a global variable then I should be able to access it in mymodule.py which I  cant.

@Lee Oh yeah, the terminology is confusing. "Globals" aren't actually global, they're module-specific.

Related: Python package can't see global variable in another file

Related: Why can't imported functions access global variables? - /r/LearnPython

Is this what you're looking for? Using global variables between files?

Or this? Visibility of global variables in imported modules

Another option might be import __main__, but I'm not sure if that's what you're looking for. If anyone else wants to post this as an answer, be my guest.

Every module has its own global scope; the only process-wide scope is the built-in scope that contains bindings for things like int, bool, str, etc. IN mymodule.test, a is a free variable that resolves to mymodule.a no matter where you call mymodule.test.

This question is similar to: Visibility of global variables in imported modules. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

If you want to print the value of the variable a using the test function in mymodule you can pass the variable to the function as an argument.
Otherwise you'll get a NameError as a is not defined in mymodule.
# mymodule.py
def test(a):
    print(a)

# main.py
import sys
import os
import mymodule

a = 'It worked'
mymodule.test(a=a)


To access local variables you would either need to pass it directly into test() as a parameter or pass vars() into test() as a parameter. Essentially you need to use parameters, thats the only convenient method outside of actually finding the variable in memory and getting the value from there which is just annoying.
tl;dr use parameters

Yes you can, use arguments like this
# main.py
import mymodule

a = 'It worked'
mymodule.test(a)

# mymodule.py
def test(a):
    print(a)

in case this is not what you are searching for, you could use a mutable object, for example like this (kinda a hotfix, there are better ways but this works):
# main.py
import mymodule

a = ['It worked', ]
mymodule.test(a)

# mymodule.py
global a
a = None
def test(_a):
    global a
    a = _a

you could also try importing circularly but safely, but this is a shit solution tbh:
# main.py
import mymodule

a = "It worked"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    mymodule.test()

# mymodule.py

def test():
    from main import a
    print(a)


"you could use a mutable object" you are not using a mutable object in that case, and the type of the object isn't relevant to what is going on there

@juanpa.arrivillaga sorry i meant to put a list and not tuple in. But it does make a difference, you can now edit the content of the list and the reference in mymodule.py can access those changes, because its mutable. That'd help when you cannot (for what ever reason) pass an argument to a function and need a global variable

But that's not what you do in your example at all.

yes, look at the code

I did look at the code. Nowhere do you mutate an object, even though you did change the object type to be a mutable one (a list instead of a tuple), but again, that just shows you that the mutability is irrelevant. You are *simply assigning to a global variables, a = _a

yes, now you can mutate the object (likely how OP intended) and it'll "change in the other file too" because its the same reference. I didn't completely provide a fully working example because i didn't want to overcomplicate the answer AND i believe it's a bad solution
